# wpf usercontrol - MVVM pattern - How to determine the time taken to load

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have a WPF app based on MVVM pattern with Prism. We have a Shell and load the views as user control into the shell. The application contains menu based navigation as in, when you click a menu tool a screen will be loaded. I want to find out the time taken for the view to load. the time should be inclusive of the time taken to call a webservice, get the model data convert it into viewmodel and show the view. Is there any way do that? Is there any tool for that that is free?

Comment: whole process is on single thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) in your shell class.  Start it when the user clicks a navigation item; add a `Loaded` event listener to the new UserControl that you create, and stop the StopWatch there.  That should give you the load time.

Comment: Just a heads up that Stopwatch class isn't extremely accurate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394020/how-accurate-is-system-diagnostics-stopwatch , not sure if it matters in this case but the discussion on that thread lists a couple of alternatives. Dunno wich one is best most of the time Stopwatch is good enough for me :)