# How to accurately time methods in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm in the middle of writing my dissertation. I have created a search application using .net c#.

I need a way to accurately time the search.

I have heard of System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch but I have read that it wasn't accurate.

So my question is what is the most accurate way to time methods and how would you implement it?

Comment: Some helpful food for thought: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394020/how-accurate-is-system-diagnostics-stopwatch

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` is really rather accurate and the perfect tool for the job. Your measurements should cover many runs of the method. This will eliminate the limited precision of the measurement.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61964/Performance-Tests-Precise-Run-Time-Measurements-wi