# Can a Timer be early?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Obviously, System.Threading.Timer callback should be expected to be late a bit. However, can it be called early?

For instance, if you start a Stopwatch and schedule the timer to run the callback in 1000 ms, is it possible that the Stopwatch will be showing 999 in the callback? Or can we count on the fact that it must show 1000 or more?

```
public sealed class EarlyTiming : IDisposable
{
    public EarlyTiming()
    {
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }

    private readonly Timer timer;
    private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch;

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        var elapsedMs = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        if (elapsedMs < 1000)
            Console.WriteLine("It was early! (" + elapsedMs + " ms)");

        try
        {
            stopwatch.Restart();
            timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably just losing a millisecond when setting up the timer. Start the stopwatch after you init the timer and it all looks fine.

Comment: Possibly of interest [How accurate is System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/394020/)

Comment: I don't think it's explicitly documented. All they [do say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is that you're limited to the resolution of the system clock but they don't even say what rounding occurs.

Comment: @DavidG It's not that there is an issue with the code provided. The question is should I expect the timer to be early sometimes when writing code or will the "It was early!" never ever be printed out.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So is that a yes? It could conceptually be early if it rounds the time down?

Comment: I think its a "it is conceivable for an implementation of the .NET Framework to exhibit such behaviour but whether any current implementation does exhibit such behaviour is unknown".

Comment: @relatively_random My point is that you **will** get "It was early!!" being printed out with this code, especially on a slower machine.

Comment: @DavidG Ah, of course. Fixing, thanks.

Comment: @DavidG On second thought, no. If you start the stopwatch early, then it can only make it seem like *more* time has passed. If you start the stopwatch after starting the timer, you could make it seem like the timer was early even though it's just the OS putting your thread on hold for a while so you didn't start the timer on time.

Comment: Yes, it's all about the accuracy of the timer and the rounding that occurs on your machine. Unfortunately computers don't work in nice decimal blocks :)